# Selenium and Angular

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to test an Angular site. The problem is that I can't click the element since no action is taken. So when I tell Selenium to find element `By.xpath`, it's not possible since I have not clicked the element. See picture below:

[image]

When I inspect the element "TEST1", the DOM is loaded. For example. see picture below:

[image]

Now I can copy full xpath:

```
/html/body/tvv-overlay/overlay/ng-transclude/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/nyps-cases/div/ul/li[1]/a/span
```

But the problem is that my Selenium script just can't click the element since it is not loaded:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/tvv-overlay/overlay/ng-transclude/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/nyps-cases/div/ul/li[1]/a/span")).click();
```

Is it not doable to test Angular with Selenium?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with explicit waits :

Also Angular based pages are dynamic in nature, so explicit wait is a way to go.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/tvv-overlay/overlay/ng-transclude/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/nyps-cases/div/ul/li[1]/a/span"))).click();
```

also if you know that `TEST1` will not change, then try this xpath.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='TEST1']"))).click();
```

**Recommendation is :**

You should always use relative `xpath`, try to avoid absolute `xpath` as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Angular will construct the element dynamically,
always go for
wait until method based on your situations.

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html